# Does New Testament accounting language have any Old Testament backing?

Tags: old-testament, word-study

Throughout the New Testament, the language of money is used to discuss sin and the gospel: words like debt, forgiveness, redeem, and impute.

For example, Colossians 2 explains forgiveness of trespasses as cancellation of **debt**. This brings in both the metaphor of a trespass as a debt and the concept that such a debt can be cancelled or "set aside" as part of regeneration by "nailing it to the cross".

In Romans 3, those who are "justified by his grace" are said to be done so "as a gift, through the **redemption** that is in Christ Jesus." Here justification (or righteousness) is made to be something that can be given as a gift, and it is done so by *redeeming* one as from bondage. Redemption (ἀπολύτρωσις here) language is often connected with paying the debt of someone else; often someone who has been made a slave to the creditor.

Finally, the language of "imputation" is sometimes used, in which funds are "transferred" from one account to another, at least on paper. I use the quotes and qualification to point out that there is no physical transference of monies, but rather, the funds are "counted" or "imputed" to the other account. This is not especially difference from the electronic transactions we have today. Romans 4 uses this language as a way of explaining how God gives righteousness to those who have faith in Jesus: "And to the one who does not work but believes in him who justifies the ungodly, his faith is **counted** as righteousness." Other translations here say that faith is "credited" is righteousness, or "reckoned" or "accounted", or can be translated "imputed". The Greek word here is λογίζεται, and these are all accounting terms with this same meaning in this context.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Does the Old Testament use this sort of language to refer to sin and righteousness?
2. In these Old Testament usages of monetary/accounting language, is such a concept of a transaction included, whereby sin is taken on by God, or that man is redeemed, his sin-debt forgiven, or righteousness granted?

Comment: I think to answer this question, we need to look at the actual words in the NT. Many are not financial terms at all. I know (because last week's sermon was on this topic) that one word for 'forgiveness' in the NT is the same word Christ used when he commanded his disciples to *leave their nets* and follow him. IOW, the word translated as *forgiveness* was already metaphorical--and of an entirely non-financial metaphor. (I'd post a link to the sermon, but my church's web site is down at the moment.)

Comment: That's a good point. Forgive is translated primary from two words, ἀφίημι and χαρίζομαι; the latter being financial language, and the former not. It looks like where "forgive" and "sins" are connected, it is ἀφίημι. I'm removing that section of the question.

Answer (score 7):

### 1. Accounting Language

It is of course a different language, but yes, the same sort of language is present in the OT as well.

**Repayment - for good *and* for evil**

> For the LORD is a God of **recompense**, He will fully **repay** [**Jeremiah 51:56**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2051:56&version=NASB)
>
> Therefore the LORD has **recompensed** me according to my righteousness, According to the cleanness of my hands in His eyes. [**Psalm 18:24**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2018:24&version=NASB)
>
> **Requite** them according to their work and according to the evil of their practices; **Requite** them according to the deeds of their hands; **Repay** them their **recompense**.  [**Psalm 28:4**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2028:4&version=NASB)

**Our Redeemer**

> As for me, I know that my **Redeemer** lives, And at the last He will take His stand on the earth.  [**Job 19:25**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2019:25&version=NASB)
>
> Do not fear, you worm Jacob, you men of Israel; I will help you,” declares the LORD, “ and your **Redeemer** is the Holy One of Israel.  [**Isaiah 41:14**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2041:14&version=NASB)

**Seeking true profit**

> Riches do not **profit** in the day of wrath, But righteousness delivers from death.  [**Proverbs 11:4**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2011:4&version=NASB)
>
> Thus says the LORD, your **Redeemer**, the Holy One of Israel, “I am the LORD your God, who teaches you to **profit**, Who leads you in the way you should go.  [**Isaiah 48:17**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2048:17&version=NASB)
>
> How blessed is the man who finds wisdom and the man who gains understanding. For her **profit** is better than the **profit** of silver and her gain better than fine gold.  [**Proverbs 3:13-14**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%203:13-14&version=NASB)

**Debt**

> The one who despises the word will be in **debt** to it, But the one who fears the commandment will be rewarded.  [**Proverbs 13:13**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2013:13&version=NASB)

**Forgiveness**

> But You are a God of **forgiveness**, Gracious and compassionate, Slow to anger and abounding in lovingkindness  [**Nehemiah 9:17**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Nehemiah%209:17&version=NASB)

### 2. Transaction / Imputation

Yes, the concept of transaction is also present in the Old Testament.  The words aren't used explicitly, but the transaction should be apparent from the text:

> Surely our griefs He Himself bore, And our sorrows He carried; Yet we ourselves esteemed Him stricken, Smitten of God, and afflicted. But He was pierced through for our transgressions, He was crushed for our iniquities; The chastening for our well-being fell upon Him, And by His scourging we are healed... the LORD has caused the iniquity of us all To fall on Him.  [**Isaiah 53**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2053&version=NASB)